# only showing button to index action when there are objects listed in the index(in the database)

Tags: ruby, button, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I have a button that links to the projects updates index action through all_project_updates_path i set in my routes. Here is my button code:

```
    <%= button_tag type: "button", :class => "radius" do %>
    <%= link_to 'Project Updates', all_project_updates_path(@project),  :style => "color: white" %>
    <% end %>
```

I want this button to only be visible when there are project updates in the database. Otherwise I want this button to dissapear. I tried:

```
    <% if all_project_updates_path(@project) != nil %> 
    <%= button_tag type: "button", :class => "radius" do %>
    <%= link_to 'Project Updates', all_project_updates_path(@project),  :style => "color: white" %>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

And also

```
<% if @updates != nil %>
<%= button_tag type: "button", :class => "radius" do %>
<%= link_to 'Project Updates', all_project_updates_path(@project),  :style => "color: white" %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Looking for a simple explanation as I am a relative beginner with ruby.

This is the route:

```
get 'all_project_updates/:id' => 'project_updates#index', as: 'all_project_updates'
```

This is my projects controller(show action)

```
def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @comments = Comment.all.where(:project_id => @project.id)
    @updates = ProjectUpdate.all.where(:project_id => @project.id)
end
```

And this is my project updates controller index action:

```
   def index
      @projectUpdates = ProjectUpdate.where(:project_id => params[:id])
      respond_to do |format|
         format.html
      end
   end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re examining a path helper, `all_project_updates_path`, when you need to be querying a model object. The `all_project_updates_path` call is a helper to return a path for linking between web pages.

```
all_project_updates_path(@project) # => /all_project_updates/1
```

So you’re really asking:

```
'/all_project_updates/1'.nil? # => false
```

Because it’s just a string, it won’t be nil.

Instead, you should be examining the `project_updates` directly. I’m not sure how your models are related, but assuming that a `Project has_many :project_updates`, try this:

```
if @project.project_updates.any?
```

That will return `true` if a `@project` has any updates.

Beyond your immediate question, I would recommend considering whether [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) are a better fit for this usage. You could declare your routes like this:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :project_updates
end
```

Then you would get `project_project_updates_path(@project)` and no longer need your custom route that pretty much duplicates that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<% if @updates.any? %>
    <%= button_tag ... %>
<% end %>
```

`@updates` is an *empty collection* (`ActiveRecord_Relation` to be precise) of `ProjectUpdate` objects if no records were found, it's not `nil`.